# modification of $2$ natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

I'm reading this part of Borceux Handbook of Categorical Algebra,
and I have a problem with the equation on the last but one line in the snippet:

$$\Xi_{A'}\ast F\alpha=G\alpha\ast \Xi_A.$$

My problem would be solved if someone gave me a commutative square with
natural (understandable) horizontal and vertical pairs of arrows and easy to see 4 corners in that diagram.

I even do not know of what type these data should be for the equation in question: are they 0-,1- or 2-cells (both, for corners and for arrows in the diagram)? I'd like to understand this Whiskering in some detail.

[image]

Comment: @KevinCarlson If I could do that by myself I wouldn't ask. I'm completely lost in this excercise though I've made a few attempts. The only possibility for me seems to see such a correct diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borceux has written $\alpha$ for both a 2-natural transformation and a 2-morphism here. Let's write $\gamma:f\to g$ instead for an arbitrary 2-morphism in $\mathcal A$. Then $G\gamma:Gf\to Gg:GA\to GA'$ while $\Xi_A:\alpha_A\to \beta_A:FA\to GA$. The repeated colon notation indicates the domain and codomain of a 2-morphism followed by the domain and codomain of the domain and codomain.

Horizontal composition of these 2-morphisms gives $$G\gamma*\Xi_A: Gf\circ \alpha_A\to Gg\circ \beta_A: FA\to GA'.$$
The other side of the equation is constructed in the same way: from $F\gamma: Ff\to Fg$ and $\Xi_{A'}:\alpha_{A'}\to \beta_{A'}$ we get $$\Xi_{A'}*F\gamma:\alpha_{A'}\circ Ff\to \beta_{A'}\circ Fg.$$
Now the naturality condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ shows we have $\alpha_{A'}\circ Ff=Gf\circ\alpha_A$ and $\beta_{A'}\circ Fg=Gg\circ \beta_A$, so that the two 2-morphisms assumed to be equal have the same domain and codomain. $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: I nearly understand what you say but not quite: I do not follow your "repeated colon notation" explanation because it is nested many times for words "domain" and "codomain". Could you please be clearer for me with this?

Comment: The first example means that the 2-morphism $G\gamma$ has domain $Gf$ and codomain $Gg$ while both of the latter 1-morphisms have domain and codomain the objects $GA$ and $GA'$ respectively. While this notation isn't universally used I find it unavoidable for 2-categorical work.

Comment: Having re-read your answer many times, I still do not follow where is (in your displayed formula) $F$ in the left hand side which we could use for the **middle part** $...\to Ff\circ\beta_A$ ? But $G$ is there in $G\gamma$ !

Comment: @user3357120 I can't understand your question. What middle part? You may be thinking of a vertical, not a vertical, composition of 2-morphisms.

Comment: I do not understand how has arisen $Ff$ in the middle term after first ":" and before second ":" ?

Comment: @user3357120 Apologies, it was an error. I fleshed out the missing detail to make up for it.

Comment: That's much better now at first sight. I'll go through it carefully later on, however.

Comment: I do not follow yet why it is useful to conclude that "... so that the two 2-morphisms assumed to be equal have the same domain and codomain." Is that what we wanted??

Comment: Yes, otherwise the definition wouldn't make sense.